# List of unregistered views

Tags: clearcase

We have a large number of unregistered views that still have tags.  We are wanting to remove these tags and views.  Does anyone know of a way to create a list of views which are unregistered with tags?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compare the [view_tag](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_data_tags_access_views.htm) and the [view_object](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_data_objs.htm) files present in the [ClearCase registry](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_intro_hostadmin_data_rgy.htm).

Any view uuid found in view_object which isn't in view_tag is an unregistered view.